# Specifying Label Color based on variable in time series esque scatter plot - Unique

Tags: r, csv, ggplot2

I've seen some variations of this question, but nothing that I've seen that has answered my unique problem here. Still learning R, but making some progress.

Simplified Data Set:

`tenor   ABBNVX  CSL    CAT
1        1.34          1.17
2        1.25   1.03

3        1.75          1.49`

I've done this:

`> read_short <- read.csv("TestShort.csv")`

`>melt_1 <- melt(read_short, measure.vars = c("ABBNVX","CSL","CAT"))`

To produce this:

`new_plot3 <- ggplot(melt_1) + geom_point(aes(tenor, value), size = 2) + geom_label_repel(aes(tenor, value, label = variable), size = 2) + scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 6, .25)) + scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 30, 1)) + xlab("Tenor") + ylab("YTM")`

[Scatter plot][1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uN3lP.png [1]

I want to introduce a third variable "Rating" which changes the color of the labels based on each rating. It doesn't need to be listed in a row like shown below, but it needs to be specific to ABBNVX, CSL, CAT, etc.

`tenor   ABBNVX  CSL    CAT
1        1.34          1.17
2        1.25   1.03

3        1.75          1.49
Rating    A    BBB     BBB+`

Example: [1]: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_text-20.png

The given example isn't using time-series esque data, just a specific fill color column, which hasn't worked in my situation since I'm using the melt function.

Any solutions/ideas much appreciated!

Comment: Use `geom_text(aes(label=Rating,color=as.factor(Rating))`

Comment: `ind_Plot <- ggplot(simple_melt) + geom_point(aes(tenor, value), size = 2) + geom_label_repel(aes(tenor, value, label = variable), size = 2) + geom_text(aes(label=Rating, color=as.factor(Rating))) + scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 10, .50)) + scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 30, 1)) + xlab("Tenor") + ylab("YTM") + ggtitle("Industrials - Capital Goods ex. Building Materials (BBB+ to BBB-)")
> ind_Plot
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Rating' not found`

Comment: FYI - Rating is listed in tenor column with 1,2,3 then Rating.

Comment: Figured out the answer. Needed to re-arrange data by putting tickers on y-axis in csv. Then used this: `ind_Plot <- ggplot(simple_melt) + geom_point(aes(variable, value), size = 2) + geom_label_repel(aes(variable, value, label = cname, fill = factor(rtg)), colour = "white", fontface = "bold", size = 2) + scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 10, .50)) + xlab("Tenor") + ylab("YTM") + ggtitle("Industrials - Capital Goods ex. Building Materials (BBB+ to BBB-)")`